angular 17 guard's Dependency injection got reinitialized or doesn't update
After login router.navigate goes to guard but in guard it doesn't get updated value.
My app.config.ts is:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (sessionService: SessionManagementService, authService: AuthService) => {
        return () => sessionService.init()
      },
      deps: [SessionManagementService, AuthService],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: DefaultInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
};

app.routes.ts is:
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./layout/main/main.routes').then(m => m.mainRoutes)
  },
  {
    canActivate: [LoginGuard],
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.routes').then(m => m.authRoutes)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];

login.component.ts is:
  @Component({
  selector: 'agro-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    PasswordModule,
    NgIf,
    InputTextModule,
    ButtonModule,
    RippleModule
  ],
  providers: [SessionManagementService, MessageService],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.scss'
})
export class LoginComponent extends BaseComponent {
  @ViewChild('orgForm') orgForm: NgForm;
  userCredential: UserCredential = new UserCredential();
  phoneRegex: RegExp = MOBILE_NUM_REGEX;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router,
              private sessionManagementService: SessionManagementService) {
    super();
  }

  login() {
    this.enableBusyState();

    this.authService.login(this.userCredential).subscribe({
      next: async response => {
        await this.sessionManagementService.refreshSession();
        await this.router.navigate(['']);
      },
      error: error=>{
        this.disableBusyState();
        this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Incorrect username/password'});
      }
    })

  }
  }

}

the refresh session updates the sessionInfo values. But when i navigate to dashboard in authGuard doesn't the updated sessionInfo value. my authguard is:
export class AuthGuard  {

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private sessionManagementService: SessionManagementService) {
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      return this.checkAccess();
  }

  checkAccess() {
    if (this.sessionManagementService.sessionInfo.isAuthenticated) {
      if (this.sessionManagementService.sessionInfo.userAuthInfo.type === 'ADMIN') {
        return true;
      }
    }
    this.router.navigate(['auth/login']);
    return false;
  }

}

i want to know Why the guard value is not updating?? and also how to change the config so that it works

what do you mean by "updated value"? I'm not sure what the expected behaviour and what the problem are. also, it would be easier to help if you provided a reproducible example

you can see inside login there is a method this.sessionManagementService.refreshSession(). this updates the session info. But after router.navigate in authgourd when i get the sessinInfo it is blank

Got the issue at last. In login.component.ts removed sessionManagementService so @Component looks like


@Component({
  selector: 'agro-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    PasswordModule,
    NgIf,
    InputTextModule,
    ButtonModule,
    RippleModule
  ],
  providers: [ MessageService],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.scss'
})



